# How to describe a guy who is popular with girls?

Tags: expressions, adjectives, phrase-requests, terminology

Perhaps I should make it clear:
 - He naturally attracts girls.
 - He doesn't chase girls and have no intention for any relationship.
 - You just see him often together with girls.

Comment: a shoe salesman?

Comment: how about charming...

Comment: How about "Fonzie"?

Comment: There is a good amount of ambiguity here. If you would clarify why the guy attracts girls it would help. Is he sexually attractive? Or perhaps he is charismatic? A good personality? And why does he have no intention for a relationship?

Comment: How about a [Casanova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giacomo_Casanova)?  Though I suppose that said name implies some form of relationship other than friendship with the many women.

Comment: Pardon me for ambiguities. Actually it has nothing to do any sort of sexual connotation or orientation. While some answers seem to suggest the guy was successful in making himself popular with women, I am looking to describe a young chap who hasn't done anything to impress the girls but girls naturally like to hang around with him and feel he is pleasant to be with. He seems to have this special charm.

Answer (score 29):

I'd like to offer [**chick magnet**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/chick+magnet): a male who seems to attract good looking females easily; someone who has many female admirers.

While *Casanova*, *player*, and *playboy* fit, they have a somewhat negative connotation (to me, at least) of having less regard for women; a chick magnet doesn't (to me) have that connotation. A **puppy** is a chick magnet!

In [6 Ways To Become The Ultimate Chick Magnet](http://elitedaily.com/dating/gentlemen/6-ways-ultimate-chick-magnet-2/) (where chick magnet is defined as *those men who seem to do absolutely nothing, but still manage to have women gravitate towards them*), two of the ways are to **borrow a baby**, and **get a puppy**. Because babies and puppies also effortlessly attract women. The site itself is misogynistic, but a chick magnet is not necessarily so any more than puppies or babies.

Ia a book of a similar title, this piece of advice can be found:

> Instead of treating women as target practice for your next sexual conquest, practice starting conversations with people you meet, without having any agenda other than to get to know them and to brighten their day...

Answer (score 27):

Well the most common term I have heard without huge sexual connotations is **ladies' man**.

> 1) A Man who spends much time with women, or is in the constant
>   company of them 2) A man who is able to pleasure women in most any
>   manner 3) A Man who tends towards female friends, rather then male
>   friends

You can also go with [playboy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playboy_%28lifestyle%29), but this hints at wealth or luxury.

A term with quite a negative connotation and meets the requirements would be **player**.

> (1) doesn't understand the meaning of relationship
>
> (2) is in full
>   reproductive mode
>
> (3) is very good at making girls think he is into
>   them (also very proficient at breaking said girls hearts)
>
> (4) often
>   "dates" several girls at several schools (girls are often unaware of
>   each other)

The use of the words depends on the context.  Playboy might be used for someone wealthier or older.  Player is very common but negative.  Ladies' man isn't exactly positive but much more so than the other two.

---

After thinking about the above answers for a minute I feel they are a bit gender biased.  These are things I would say as a man - especially player.  Trying to think of how some women I know describe such men I would offer different suggestions.

One would be **heart throb**.  This would be very extreme and could be used for those who are ultra popular.

> Someone who is an object of infatuation.

And probably the term I have heard women in my life use the most is sweetheart.  "Oh John is such a sweetheart.  He is so caring and nice."  To guys we might think John is a big player but if he is friends with a ton of girls, they will most likely refer to him as a **sweetheart**.

> Someone who's kind-hearted, nice, sweet, great person, personality,
>   lovely to be around and just a great friend.

Comment: As for the (relative?) lack of sexual connotation with "ladies' man": as far as i know, i've never seen/heard the word "pleasure" used as a verb in anything but a sexual context.  To my (US) ear, that part of definition 2, about being "able to pleasure women in most any manner", is *almost purely* sexual.

Comment: @cHao - it is men that usually equate the word pleasure with sex.  In the OP's criteria this is really a non-issue though.  He doesn't mention if the guy has sex with the girls or not.  In my heart I hope he is getting a little action though.

Comment: It's not so much the *word* "pleasure", as specifically the transitive verb.  As a noun, it's not quite as fraught with sexual connotations (though it can never fully get away from them).  Same with the intransitive verb, apparently, though i never see/hear that used in modern writing/speech.

Answer (score 7):

In Britain the older generation would call him **a ladies' man**. I hope I have punctuated it correctly. Does anyone think it should be *a lady's man*?

Comment: I think a *lady's man* might be some kind of servant or protector. Besides, we want multiple women. Your choice holds up.

Comment: Great term.  I think I got you by a few seconds!

Comment: @WS2 I don't know that you even need possessiveness; *ladies man* would work as simply 'a man of the ladies', would it not?

Comment: @TylerH   'A man of the ladies' is a possessive. It is just that in English we have a shortened way of saying *la plume de ma tante* (the pen of my aunt). It is 'my aunt's pen'. Thus what in French would be *un homme des dames* would be 'a ladies' man'.

Answer (score 7):

[Urban Dictionary: Don Juan](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=don%20juan)

> A Great Lover. A Great Friend. A man that gave many women sexual
>   gratification. Sometimes people call friends or people who are smooth
>   with ladies Don Juan.
>
> That jon, he's such a don juan.

[Wiki: Don Juan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%5fJuan)

> Don Juan is used synonymously for "womanizer", especially in Spanish
>   slang, and is often used in reference to hypersexuality. This is
>   evident in William Shakespeare's Much Ado About Nothing.

Answer (score 5):

What you *really* want, is a *Mack*:

[image]

Or a *Playa* / *Player*:

[image]

They are often used interchangeably nowadays.

Comment: This is used almost exclusively in the African-American community, so if you're trying to reach a wide audience, I would avoid it.

Comment: While that used to be true, when it comes to using the word, it all depends on context. Lexicon once labeled as *Black* or *African-American* has made it's way mainstream. I'd hypothesize given the reach of tv commercials and now even rap music, most Americans in the 18-49 age demographic would know what it means for a guy to be a player. While I wouldn't use this in a formal speech, most words that describe a guy who is popular with females are going to have sexual connotations in some form or fashion.

Comment: ‘Player’ is certainly not restricted to AAVE, but I’d say ‘mack’ is still quite heavily in the AAVE camp. I don’t think I’ve ever heard the term used by anyone who wasn’t either black or trying to be. It instantly makes me think of [Return of the Mack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uB1D9wWxd2w).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It is used less now than before, particularly in favor of Player, and probably not used at all among the younger AA crowd.

Comment: I wasn't referring to 'player' - which is used a lot on talk shows and definitely mainstream. "Mack" or "macking" is generally not used in popular media.

Comment: @Jasmine I see now.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently nobody has mentioned it yet, so I’ll put forth [*stud*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20stud).

The term stud comes from the animal-husbandry world where it refers to a male whose purpose is to mate with females and produce offspring. Likewise, male humans who are perceived to have “game” and be able to “score” easily with women are often dubbed studs.

Answer (score 4):

*A lady-killer or Casanova* may also be used to indicate popularity with girls.

Answer (score 2):

A less strong noun, useful for either sex, is *charmer*.  He could be a charmer because he is intelligent, considerate, a good listener, or even because he is a musician.

Answer (score 0):

In older language there is the term womanizer. But for a young man today I would simply say "a nice guy the girls are fond of".

Comment: Womanizer has *strongly* negative connotations. It implies, at a minimum, neglect or disregard, and more often than not, actual violence.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I disagree; James Bond is regularly described as a womanizer, but he isn't violent toward women. Womanizers are simply nicer versions of players.

Comment: James Bond treats women like garbage.

Comment: A womanizer is a man who habitually has multiple sexual partners, whether concurrently or sequentially.  It has a strong connotation of immorality or exploitation.