# What's a word/phrase for a player/seducer?

Tags: synonyms, pejorative-language

I can't seem to remember this particular word/phrase. I'm almost certain it's a two-word phrase. It specifically refers to someone who is skilled with the ladies, ie, someone who knows the tricks of the trade.

Usage:
- "Unless you're a X-Y, that's not going to work with her."

Edit : 
I'm not looking for 'ladies man', 'casanova', 'womanizer' etc.
This phrase refers to someone who's more of a pro and one who is serious about his business.

Comment: Have a look here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163450/how-to-describe-a-guy-who-is-popular-with-girls/163457#163457

Comment: +1 for using the phrase " **skilled with the ladies** "

Comment: Duplicate of [How to describe a guy who is popular with girls?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163450/how-to-describe-a-guy-who-is-popular-with-girls).

Comment: It's not any of the words that are there in the above two questions. I'm looking for a very specific phrase and not looking for classmate terms. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Did you look at both questions, if you had you would have noticed they are identical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also be looking for the phrase **pickup artist.**

This used to be a synonym for a "ladies' man," someone who was good at the skills and techniques of seduction.

However, it's recently begun to be associated with a specific subset of extremely creepy people who use a specific range of extremely creepy techniques to pick up women. If you are talking about people taking things "seriously," this might be what you mean--but you should be aware that most people now consider "pickup artist" to also carry the strong implication of being highly misogynistic and a borderline psychopath.

Comment: Awesome. This is EXACTLY what I was looking for !

Answer (score 3):

***"Smooth operator"*** is someone who is good at winning over women.  It's also the title of a [song](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/sade/smoothoperator.html) about that same behavior - it has a slightly negative connotation.

It might be exciting to get the attention of a ***smooth operator*** (or if you're a man, to have the skills of one) but you probably wouldn't want to take him home to meet your parents.

Answer (score 3):

How about smooth-talker

Definition in Urban dictionary:

> Someone who has a very rare ability to say all the right things at the
>   right time. Even when a situation is not in their favor, by the end of
>   the night their uncanny ability with words has turned a unfavorable
>   situation into an advantage. They are charming and possess all the
>   people skills then some, they can talk their way out of or in into
>   anything they want. Even more deadly if the person is hot.

Answer (score 2):

*Incubus* is a paranormal term for a male entity that seduces women. A demon with supernatural abilities.

*Ace* is a skilled performer in many contexts.

*Gigolo* is another word for a man who is a professional romancer.

*Rock Star* is one who attracts women, but doesn't necessarily have skill. See also *movie star*.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

He is a real **ladies man.**

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry that this is only one word but a **gigolo** is a professional player.

> a young man paid or financially supported by a woman, typically an
>   older woman, to be her escort or lover.

It is sometimes referred to as a playboy but the word gigolo is much more pointed.

Answer (score 1):

Casanova

A smooth-talking charmer who has mastered the art of finding, meeting, attracting and seducing beautiful women into the bedroom. One he accomplishes his goal, he leaves the woman in fear of having a relationship and proceeds to find his next conquest.

Comment: Problem is... the OP specifically said: "I'm not looking for 'ladies man', 'casanova', 'womanizer' etc"

Answer (score 0):

Is [sweettalker/sweet talker](http://pt.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sweet-talk) the word you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

**Philanderer**

> a man who readily or frequently enters into casual sexual
>   relationships with women; a womanizer.