# A word or a substitute word for a casanova type of guy

Tags: vocabulary

What do you call a guy who is dating many girls at the same time?

Comment: Casanova: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/Casanova?s=t

Comment: Promiscuous? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuity

Comment: Deuce Bigalow, Male Gigolo.

Comment: This question has been asked before, and more than once.

Comment: I can't vote to close this question as a duplicate because the one I indicated was incorrect. But these are all possible duplicates: [How to describe a guy who is popular with girls?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163450/how-to-describe-a-guy-who-is-popular-with-girls) and [What's a word/phrase for a player/seducer?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166127/whats-a-word-phrase-for-a-player-seducer) Could someone else vote to close this question?

Answer (score 4):

1. a [Don Juan](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Don%20Juan); a ladies' man, a successful seducer of women, an obsessive and unscrupulous pursuer of women. From the legendary nobleman who seduced hundreds of women and was eventually damned for his immoral ways.
2. a [womanizer](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Womanizer); a promiscuous heterosexual man
3. a [philanderer](https://www.google.com/search?q=philanderer&oq=philande&aqs=chrome.2.0l3j69i57j0j69i60.30030j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8); a man who readily or frequently enters into casual sexual relationships with women.

Answer (score 3):

Another good option is [Lothario](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lothario): a man whose chief interest is seducing women.

The similar, more modern (slangy) term is [player](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=player).